# How Can we have multiple app with same apk file in playstore?

Tags: android, google-play

Can we have multiple app with same apk file? We have developed POS application which support multiple stores. Each store will have their own icon and/or app name. However all these stores will be handled by our single apk file. So in this case in play store there will be multiple icons or multiple app names but only one apk file.

Please let us know how can we do this.

Comment: i don't know but [This](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html) may help .

Comment: So the app display name and stores depending on what? Assume I am a user I go to playstore what will I go download? Which one? If it doesnt matter build more apks and not just one!

Comment: not possible in single apk but what will work for you is build variants in single code base using gradle ( assuming you are using android studio ) - https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

Comment: @ADM is  given exact solution,but is this same work in playstore?

Comment: Read the documentation carefully . You will find out the trick . Google documents are well organized they rarely miss anything in topic .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have same APK in PlayStore, but you can have same source code with different package name.

You can manage same source code with different flavor(app name, icon) in same project in Android Studio.

[See Blog For Product Flavors](http://codetoart.com/building-multiple-versions-of-an-android-app-product-flavors/)

Comment: I have 100 store and  we need to provide 100 apk to every store playstore,that i dont want. single app work for 100 store. and it should be search by every storename but have single APK in playstore.

Comment: You want single APK will be for 100 stores in PlayStore. That is not possible my dear friend. YOU WILL NEVER FIND SOLUTION  :)

Comment: http://codetoart.com/building-multiple-versions-of-an-android-app-product-flavors/ but,this will help me I think I can reach near about 100 store find their functionality using single apk and install with store wise name and icon.